# Unable to show my ArrayList data in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, arraylist, android-listview, android-adapter

When I put my data in `ArrayList` and adding to `ListView`. But there has no data show on `ListView` but I am sure those data has been retrieved.

The System output for testing is correct.( my data )

This is my `pseudo-code`:

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import com.parse.FindCallback;
    import com.parse.ParseException;
    import com.parse.ParseObject;
    import com.parse.ParseQuery;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class query_page extends AppCompatActivity {
    public ArrayList<String> show_Location, show_Messages;
    public ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_query_page);
        show_Location = new ArrayList<String>();
        show_Messages = new ArrayList<String>();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        //Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        //Parse.initialize(this,"Kfl0hkIIHec4uwhufpAc9luukPhz2H4QPEQeCgZY","S0eka3H15A58ACGKuvbnIsnKFS6gVQRz9BUCTnQw");
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Danger");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (ParseObject j : list) {
                        show_Location.add(j.getString("DangerLocation"));
                        show_Messages.add(j.getString("DangerMessage"));
                        System.out.println("Location: " + j.getString("DangerLocation"));
                        System.out.println("Messages: " + j.getString("DangerMessage"));
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(query_page.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, show_Location);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Exception occur! ");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.s1011423_term_project.query_page">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post full code adapter , please!

Comment: Are you sure you're receiving data from Parse? Can you please post the xml for your activity? BTW in Java we use CamelCase, no underscore

Comment: @QuangDoan, the there is my full code, thanks

Comment: @jegesh, add XML files already. I am newcomer in Android, thanks for ur advice !

Comment: Please do not change the contents of your question with the existing answers and add **additional information** after a solution has been provided. This causes the answers to become invalidated.

Comment: Naming your `ListView` 'listView' may be shadowing, or be shadowed by, a standard Android component.  Try naming it something slightly...more original.

Comment: @jegesh How does that shadow (or be shadowed by)  anything? The "L" is lowercased. Android Studio will even autocomplete that variable to "listView"

Comment: Thanks everyone suggestions , I am new in Android and stackoverflow. And I just solve my problem by using String array instead of ArrayList type, is this the correct solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your adapter a field in your class along with the Arraylist.

```
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
```

And **do not** initialize the adapter within the Parse callback. You don't need any data in your list to set the adapter.

So move these lines

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(query_page.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, show_Location);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Directly after

```
listView = ...;
```

At the end of `done` in the Parse code, call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The reason being is that you change the underlying data. You could, alternatively directly add to the adapter.

```
adapter.add(j.getString("DangerLocation"));
```

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007, I had modify my code but there has error occur...              "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: That has nothing to do with what I posted. Most likely `j.getString("DangerLocation")` returned null because `DangerLocation` is not a string in `j`. If this post helped you, you can accept it and create a new question with your new error

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that the ListView defined in activity_mail.xml does not have 0 as width and height(It may becoming 0 during infer constraints)
Make sure that it has values like match_parent or any value greater than 0
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"